# Фукнция выполняется дважды

Tags: redux

Я не могу понять, почему функция ***returnSlidesReducer()*** выполняется дважды. Я использую Redux.

Мой редюсер **slides.js** (читает json файл и отправляет данные в store):

```
import jsonFile from '../sliderContent.json';

const returnSlidesReducer = (slidesContent) => {
    console.log(slidesContent);
    return slidesContent;
}

returnSlidesReducer(jsonFile);

export default returnSlidesReducer;
```

И мой **index.js**:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App';
import {createStore} from 'redux';
//import allReducers from './reducers';
import SlidesReducer from './reducers/slides';

const store = createStore(SlidesReducer);

ReactDOM.render(
    <App />, 
    document.getElementById('root')
);
```

В консоли я получаю

1. {slider:Array(3)}
2. undefined

И в итоге в store уходит значение undefined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

наверное нужно так

```
let res = returnSlidesReducer(jsonFile);
export default res;
```